# How to get the class property for each HTML component inside a parent div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello to the community.

This is my HTML code, what I want is to get the class property, only those that start with 'col-sm-', and that is inside the parent div, only identifying it by the property 'kyros'

```
<div id="div_wid_001" class="widget-main">
    <div kyros="div_frm_gro_001" class="form-group">
        <label id="lbl_001" kyros="lbl_001" class="col-sm-2 control-label no-padding-right">Label 001:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <input id="txt_001" kyros="txt_001" class="form-control bas_com" type="text">
            <div class="button-wrapper">
                <a href="#" id="hre_edi_txt_001" class="btn_editar"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></a>
                <a href="#" id="hre_rem_txt_001" class="btn_remover"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-times"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="div_sm_003" class="col-sm-8 frm_com ui-droppable"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var div_parent = 'div_frm_gro_001';
var col_sm = 'col-sm-';
/// 

$('div[kyros='+div_parent+']').children('div[class^='+col_sm+']').each(function () {
    var kyr_class = $(this).attr('class');
    console.log(kyr_class);
});
```

You should get the following result:

**col-sm-2 control-label no-padding-right**

**col-sm-2**

**col-sm-8 frm_com ui-droppable**

Comment: Could you clarify the question a bit further? Do you already have the JS code? If so, what's the error you're facing?

Comment: @jithinpt: The OP's code isn't finding all three of the elements he/she wants to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two changes you need to make:

1. <s>Use `find` so you search all descendants, not just `children`.</s> *Not sure why I thought one of your targets was nested inside another, but it isn't; so `children` is fine if you know they'll be children.*
2. Remove the `div` restriction from your `div[class^=...]`, because one of the elements you want to find is a `label`, not a `div`.

Example:

```js
var div_parent = 'div_frm_gro_001';
var col_sm = 'col-sm-';
/// 

$('div[kyros='+div_parent+']')
    .children('[class^='+col_sm+']')
    .each(function () {
        var kyr_class = $(this).attr('class');
        console.log(kyr_class);
});
```

```html
<div id="div_wid_001" class="widget-main">
    <div kyros="div_frm_gro_001" class="form-group">
        <label id="lbl_001" kyros="lbl_001" class="col-sm-2 control-label no-padding-right">Label 001:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <input id="txt_001" kyros="txt_001" class="form-control bas_com" type="text">
            <div class="button-wrapper">
                <a href="#" id="hre_edi_txt_001" class="btn_editar"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></a>
                <a href="#" id="hre_rem_txt_001" class="btn_remover"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-times"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="div_sm_003" class="col-sm-8 frm_com ui-droppable"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**But**, that's fragile; it requires that the `col-sm-` be at the **beginning** of the `class` attribute. If someone adds a class before it later in development, this will break.

Instead, use a "contains" (`*=`) as a rough filter and then `filter` to fine-tune it:

```
$('div[kyros='+div_parent+']')
    .children('[class*='+col_sm+']') // or .find to include descendants
    .filter(function() {
        // Filter out foo-col-sm-, requiring that col-sm- be at the
        // beginning of the string or after a space
        return this.className.startsWith(col_sm) || this.className.indexOf(" " + col_sm) != -1;
    })
    . // ...
```

Example (I've changed the third match so `col-sm-` isn't at the beginning of `class`):

```js
var div_parent = 'div_frm_gro_001';
var col_sm = 'col-sm-';
/// 

$('div[kyros='+div_parent+']')
    .children('[class*='+col_sm+']')
    .filter(function() {
        return this.className.startsWith(col_sm) || this.className.indexOf(" " + col_sm) != -1;
    })
    .each(function () {
        var kyr_class = $(this).attr('class');
        console.log(kyr_class);
    });
```

```html
<div id="div_wid_001" class="widget-main">
    <div kyros="div_frm_gro_001" class="form-group">
        <label id="lbl_001" kyros="lbl_001" class="col-sm-2 control-label no-padding-right">Label 001:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <input id="txt_001" kyros="txt_001" class="form-control bas_com" type="text">
            <div class="button-wrapper">
                <a href="#" id="hre_edi_txt_001" class="btn_editar"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></a>
                <a href="#" id="hre_rem_txt_001" class="btn_remover"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-times"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="div_sm_003" class="ui-droppable col-sm-8 frm_com"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't getting the first result you expect because you are only looking for div.

```
$('div[kyros='+div_parent+']').children('div[class^='+col_sm+']').each(function () {
var kyr_class = $(this).attr('class');
console.log(kyr_class);
});
```

If you change your selector, it will work as expected

`.children('*[class^='+col_sm+']')`

Answer (score -1):

This solution will work :

```
var div_parent = 'div_frm_gro_001';
var col_sm = 'col-sm-';
$('div[kyros='+div_parent+']').find('[class^='+col_sm+']').each(function () {
    alert($(this).attr('class'));
    console.log($(this).attr('class'));
});
```

Here is solution done : https://jsfiddle.net/txmmboxf/

I've updated it for lebel selection, now it will select any element start with class name.